# Nodejs - error on deploy because found any require?

Tags: node.js, deployment

I got this message deploying an app on Azure and than access to the endpoint:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\home\site\wwwroot\index.js from C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js not supported.Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\296456~1.8\nodejs\node_modules\diagnostic-channel\dist\src\patchRequire.js:16:46)at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\home\site\wwwroot\index.js from C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js not supported.Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\296456~1.8\nodejs\node_modules\diagnostic-channel\dist\src\patchRequire.js:16:46)at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
```

I've already set `"type": "module"` on package.json, what's wrong?

Here's the basic code:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import createError from 'http-errors';
import moment from 'moment';

// init
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || '';
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), `.env${nodeEnv ? '.' + nodeEnv : ''}`) });

// mongodb
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING)
    .then((x) => {
        console.log(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + ` - Connected Database: "${x.connections[0].name}"`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error connecting to mongo', err.reason);
    })

// generic
const app = express();
{
    // cors
    app.use(cors());

    // port
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + ' - API Started. Endpoint: http://localhost:' + port + '/');
    })

    // body parser
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
}

// rest api
try {
    // account
    app.use('/api/account', AccountRouter);

    // exchange
    app.use('/api/exchange/', ExchangeRouter);

    // default
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Welcome');
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('REST API Error', error);
}

// errors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    next(createError(404));
});
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + " - " + err.message);
    if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
});
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "@myapp/backend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node index.js",
        "serve": "supervisor index.js",
        "job_orders": "set NODE_ENV=production& supervisor jobs/orders.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "crypto": "^1.0.1",
        "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "http-errors": "^2.0.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.3",
        "mongoose": "^6.4.0",
        "supervisor": "^0.12.0",
        "ws": "^8.8.0"
    }
}
```

I followed this: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/supporting-es6-import-on-windows-app-service-node-js-iisnode/ba-p/3639037

but now it renders the index.js as "text" instead of execute it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with Windows App Service. You can solve this by simply creating a new file next to your `index.js` and configuring it as the iisnode's entry point ( in web.config). Microsoft suggest you call it something like `run.cjs` with the following content in your case:

```
import("./index.js");
```

As per the [docs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/supporting-es6-import-on-windows-app-service-node-js-iisnode/ba-p/3639037).

Ensure the web.config file is updated with `path="run.cjs"` and `url="run.cjs"` attributes.